# Use fat arrow function to change React.Component in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

is it possible to render a React.Component over other React.Component using just fat arrow function, using state seems unnecessary in my case as there is no need to close the opened Component. I am trying to achieve the simplest to render a React.Component over other React.Component.

I am trying to do it like this:

```
<Button onPress={() => { return (<ShowOtherReactComponent/>); }} >Show OtherComponent</Button>
```

this is calling the `<ShowOtherReactComponent/>` I know that because I called an alert function from `constructor` but! nothing is rendering. why is that? how can I do this?

*PS: this approach may be wrong, but still wanna see how it can be done. for science.*

Comment: Why would you want to return `jsx` from an `onPress` handler?

Comment: @Dupocas what should I do?

Comment: Could you elaborate better? What is the desired behavior? Toggle between components?

Comment: @Dupocas one way flow, no going back, so no need to toggle, just show a component

Comment: You shouldn't return it, but I think you could add it to the state. I'll try to show an example

Comment: I am trying on my side as well, lets see if its possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't return `jsx` from your handlers. Usually to show and or toggle components [**conditional rendering**](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) is the way to go.

Instead of returning `<ShowOtherReactComponent/>` from `onPress` you conditionally render the component based on a `boolean` binded to the local state and change the state instead.

```
const Component = () =>{
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false)

    const onPress = () => setShow(true)

    return(
        <>
            <button onPress={onPress}> Show </button>
            { show && <ShowOtherReactComponent/> }
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made an example to show what you could potentially do if you wanted a button to add components to display:

```
import React from 'react';
import autoBind from 'react-autobind';

export default class ButtonTest extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            extraComponents : []
        };

        autoBind(this);
    }

    addComponent() {
        const newComponent = (<p>I'm a new component</p>);
        this.setState({extraComponents: [...this.state.extraComponents, newComponent]})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.addComponent}>add component</button>

                {this.state.extraComponent}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I've checked it and it works.

Comment: Hello, what's that mean? `[...this.state.extraComponents, newComponent]` I think extraComponents at first time is empty!

Comment: @DevAS at first it is empty! and that's ok. `[...arr, newElement]` creates a new array out of all the elements inside of `arr`, with `newElement` added to the end of it. And if `arr` is empty, it just creates a new array with `newElement`

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView, View, Text, Button, Dimensions } from 'react-native'


const App = () => {

    const [visibilityOfOtherView, setvisibilityOfOtherView] = useState(false)
    const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window')
    const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Math.round(height)
    const SCREEN_WIDTH = Math.round(width)

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ height: SCREEN_HEIGHT, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, }}>

            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
                <Text style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
                    First Components
                </Text>
                <Button
                    title='Toggle Components View'
                    onPress={() => setvisibilityOfOtherView(!visibilityOfOtherView)}
                />
            </View>

            {
                visibilityOfOtherView ?
                    <View style={{ height: SCREEN_HEIGHT, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
                        <Text style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
                            Secound Components
                        </Text>
                        <Button
                            title='Toggle Components View'
                            onPress={() => setvisibilityOfOtherView(!visibilityOfOtherView)}
                        />
                    </View>
                    : null
            }

        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

export default App
```